# C++ Linked list - destructor implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor

I have no idea how to create destructor to my implementation of linked list. I tried something like that:

```
template <class T>
Lista<T>::~Lista()
{
    while (head) Delete(); 
}
```

but it was deleting all list when i just wanted to delete one element. Any solutions? Maybe it is mistake to keep a head in a static field?

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Lista
{
private:
    Lista *next;
    T data;
    static Lista *head;

public:
    Lista();
    void Delete();  //to delete
    void Delete2(Lista *);  //just for testing
    void Delete_wyb(int);   //to delete selected
    int Add(T data);    //to add
    T Pobierz(int which);   //to return data
    void Sortuj();  //to sort
    int Ile();  //how many elements

    ~Lista();
};
```

And the .cpp excerpt

```
#include "Lista.h"

template<class T>
Lista<T>* Lista<T>::head = NULL;

template <class T>
Lista<T>::Lista()
{
}

template <class T>
void Lista<T>::Delete()
{
    if (head == NULL) cout << "Error\n";
    else
    {
        Lista *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

template <class T>
void Lista<T>::Delete_wyb(int choice)  //deletes by choice
{
    Lista *tmp;
    Lista *tmp2;
    int licznik = 0; //licznik is just for counting
    int licznik2 = 0;

    if (licznik == choice) Delete(); 
    else
    {
        tmp2 = head;

        for (; licznik != choice; licznik++)
        {
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }

        tmp = head;

        for (; licznik2 != choice - 1; licznik2++)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

        tmp->next = tmp2->next;
        delete tmp2;
        tmp2 = NULL;
    }
}

template <class T>
int Lista<T>::Add(T data) 
{
    Lista *tmp;
    tmp = new Lista;

    if (tmp == NULL) return 0;
    else
    {
        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = head;
        head = tmp;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the problem itself is that in `Delete()` you delete an element properly, then set the head again and in destructor, you call `while(head)`, instead of say `if(head)`... but WHY THE HELL IS `head` STATIC?

Comment: To know where is the beggining of the list?

Comment: Now think about what happens if you want to have two separate, independent lists of the same `T`.

Comment: They'll have the same 'beggining'?  I thought that it will be the beggining only in one list. 
Lista<int>* A0 = new Lista<int>;
Lista<int>* A1 = new Lista<int>;
So A1 head and A0 head will be the same?

Comment: Yes, that is what `static` means. Anyway, what you want to do to solve it, is to have a class like `class list { node* head; struct node{ node* prev, T item, node* next }` and go from there.

Comment: So, my big mistake with a static field, I thought it was comprehensible for me. It must be slist, without prev. What is a goal of creating struct node? That I will not be creating List objects, but node objects and destructor in class List will be launched only if my A0 will be deleted and i can freely delete next without touching List object and there will be only one List object for separate list? Some kind of mother of the list? Sorry for newbie questions, I'm not sure I grasped it.

Comment: Assuming I understand your comment properly, yes. It allows you to have nice interface and encapsulation. `list<int> list; list.add(2); list.add(3);` and you just take care of nodes themselves separately. Assuming you want to delete head when removing, you call `list.delete_head()` and inside perform something like `node* tmp = head; head = head->next; delete tmp;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `head` pointer and delete the element:

```
while (head)
{
  Lista * temp = head;
  head = head->next;
  delete temp;
}
```